# Load data from flat file using php

Tags: php, text-files

I have a text file that serves as a database and have the following data format:

```
*NEW RECORD
NM = Stackoverflow
DT = 9/15/2006
DS = Overflow
DS = Stack
DS = stackoverflow.com
DS = FAQ

*NEW RECORD
NM = Google
DT = 9/4/1998
DS = G+
DS = Google
DS = Search engine
DS = Search
```

You get the idea..

The problem is I do not know how to load specific data from a specific record using PHP. especially, when the data is not in an array format. Do I need to convert data to array format? or is their a way that I can retrieve information from my current format?

For example, what is the equivelent code for this mysql query:

```
SELECT DT FROM MY_TXT WHERE DS = "Google"
```

Comment: did you tried JSON

Comment: since you didn't say not to, i have to ask: why not use a database?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Searching for data and removing data from a text file using php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624966/searching-for-data-and-removing-data-from-a-text-file-using-php)

Comment: @Terminus This is an external database that gets updated every year. Not going to add, edit, or update.. just retrieve. I think I would run into more trouble converting it to a different format.

Comment: my condolences, sounds like no fun to maintain. i think the possible dupe's function can be converted to for your uses. (explode on *NEWRECORD, foreach all the "records" do `preg_match('/^DS = Google\s*$/', $record);` on each record. Stick the ones that match into a $results array. done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're stuck with this format, you need a custom deserialisation mechanism. Here's one that works for your sample data:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set("UTC");

class Record {
    public $nm = null;
    public $dt = null;
    public $ds = [];

    function isValid() {
        return $this->nm !== null && $this->dt !== null && count($this->ds) > 0;
    }

    function isEmpty() {
        return $this->nm == null && $this->dt == null && count($this->ds) == 0;
    }
}

function deserialise($filename, $newLineSeparator = "\n") {
    $incompleteRecords = 0;
    $records = [];
    $lines = explode($newLineSeparator, file_get_contents($filename));

    if ($lines)
        $lines[] = "*NEW RECORD";

    $record = new Record();
    foreach ($lines as $line) {
        $line = trim($line);
        if ($line == "*NEW RECORD") {
            if ($record->isValid())
                $records[] = $record;
            else if (!$record->isEmpty())
                $incompleteRecords++;

            $record = new Record();
        } else if (substr($line, 0, 5) == "NM = ") {
            $record->nm = substr($line, 5);
        } else if (substr($line, 0, 5) == "DT = ") {
            $record->dt = strtotime(substr($line, 5));
        } else if (substr($line, 0, 5) == "DS = ") {
            $record->ds[] = substr($line, 5);
        }
    }

    echo "Found $incompleteRecords incomplete records.\n";

    return $records;
}
```

I tried it with your data and I get this output:

```
Found 0 incomplete records.
Array
(
    [0] => Record Object
        (
            [nm] => Stackoverflow
            [dt] => 1158278400
            [ds] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Overflow
                    [1] => Stack
                    [2] => stackoverflow.com
                    [3] => FAQ
                )

        )

    [1] => Record Object
        (
            [nm] => Google
            [dt] => 904867200
            [ds] => Array
                (
                    [0] => G+
                    [1] => Google
                    [2] => Search engine
                    [3] => Search
                )

        )

)
```

Is this what you want?

**Some considerations**

- Loads everything in memory at once; no batching
- Uses `strtotime` to parse dates into timestamps; you might want to just load them as strings (easier), or use the `DateTime` class. If you're using `strtotime`, please set the adecuate timezone first, as in the example (`date_default_timezone_set`).
- Assumes that a record is invalid if no NM is set, or no DT is set, or no DS entries exist. You can modify this constraint by adapting the `isValid` method on the `Record` class.
- No error-handling for broken format, lowercase, etc.
- Assumes `\n` as the newline separator. If you have `\r\n` or `\r`, just invoke the `deserialise` function with them as the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Without validation!!

```
$filename = "test.txt"; // Your Filename ;-)

$t = new FlatDbSearch($filename);

var_dump($t->select('DT', 'DS = "Google"'));

class FlatDbSearch {

    protected $lines;

    public function __construct($filename) {
        $this->lines = file($filename, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
    }

    public function select($column, $where) {
        $parts = explode("=", $where);
        $searchKey = trim(str_replace('"', '', $parts[0]));
        $searchValue = trim(str_replace('"', '', $parts[1]));
        $column = trim(str_replace('"', '', $column));

        $lines = $this->searchForward($searchKey, $searchValue);
        if (count($lines) !== 0) {
            $results = $this->searchBackward($column, $lines);
            return $results;
        }
        return array();
    }

    protected function searchBackward($column, $lines) {
        $results = array();
        foreach($lines as $key) {
            for ($i = $key; $i > -1; $i--) {
                $parts = explode("=", $this->lines[$i]);
                if ($column == trim(str_replace('"', '', $parts[0]))) {
                    $results[] = trim(str_replace('"', '', $parts[1]));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return $results;
    }

    protected function searchForward($searchKey, $searchValue) {
        $result = array();
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($this->lines); $i++) {
            $parts = explode("=", $this->lines[$i]);
            if (trim(str_replace('"', '', $parts[0])) == $searchKey) {
                if (trim(str_replace('"', '', $parts[1])) == $searchValue) {
                    $result[] = $i;
                }
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```